# Mudança no valor do Array

Tags: c, array

Comecei a aprender sobre C, e fazendo algumas questões do [URI](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1250) encontrei um erro que não sei como corrigir. Ao inserir os valores dentro do array tiro, ele insere todos os valores corretamente, mas ao passar pelo scan do array pulo, tiro[0] fica 0. Alguém sabe o motivo disso e como posso corrigir?

- A primeira linha da entrada contém um inteiro N que indica o número de casos de teste. Cada caso de teste é composto por 3 linhas.
- A primeira linha contém um inteiro T (1 ≤ T ≤ 50) que indica o número de tiros.
- A segunda linha contém T inteiros, que representam a sequência das alturas às quais os tiros estão sendo disparados. Cada elemento da sequência será entre 1 e 7, inclusive.
- A terceira linha da entrada contém a string "pulos", que representa a sequência de pulos que KiloMan tentará; 'J' significa que ele irá pular e 'S' significa que ele ficará parado
- No caso de ele ficar parado a altura ser 1 ou 2, ele será atingido. E caso ele pule e a altura seja 3 ou maior, também será atingido
- No final é necessário apresentar o número de vezes que ele é atingido

Casos de teste que estou usando, o primeiro retorna 25 (o certo é 26) e o segundo retorna 6 (o certo é 5)

1
48
6 5 4 4 2 7 1 4 5 1 6 5 6 5 5 4 1 1 2 7 5 6 7 5 5 3 4 7 2 5 6 6 5 3 7 4 1 4 1 2 2 7 3 1 7 7 7 2
JJJSJJSSJSSSJJJSJSSSSJSSJSSJSSJJSJJSSSJJJSJSJJJJ

1
16
4 4 3 3 4 4 5 4 5 6 1 3 5 7 2 3
SSSSJSSSSJJJJSJJ

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int rep, mov, ace, i, i2;
    scanf("%d", &rep);
    for(i = 0; i < rep; i++){
        ace = 0;
        scanf("%d", &mov);

        int tiro[mov];
        for(i2 = 0; i2 < mov; i2++){
            scanf("%d", &tiro[i2]);
        }
        printf("%d\n", tiro[0]); //Valor de tiro continua sendo o mesmo

        char pulo[mov];
        scanf("%s", &pulo);

        printf("%d\n", tiro[0]); //Valor de tiro já virou 0
        for(i2 = 0; i2 < mov; i2++){
            if((tiro[i2] <= 2 && pulo[i2] == 'S') || (tiro[i2] >= 3 && pulo[i2] == 'J')){
                ace++;
            }
            printf("O teste %d, com os valores %d/%c teve %d acerto(s)\n", i2+1, tiro[i2], pulo[i2], ace);
        }
        printf("%d\n", ace);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não tão off-topic: **URI** é **U**niversidade **R**egional **I**ntegrada, uma universidade de Erechim, RS. **Online Judge** é uma plataforma de programação competitiva, ou algo assim.

Esse problema é iterativo: são `N` casos de teste e cada caso tem um certo número de disparos da tal arma. E para cada disparo a reação será `J` ou `S`, *jump* ou *stand still*. 2 linhas trazem os pares altura do tiro / atitude do jogador, e a saída para cada série é o número de vezes em que o cara foi atingido.

A decisão é uma tabela: a altura do tiro vai de 1 a 7. No caso de ele ficar parado a altura ser 1 ou 2, ele será atingido. E caso ele pule e a altura seja 3 ou maior, também será atingido. Nada mais. Eis a tabela:

```
Alt < 3    Pula?      Resultado
   N         N          A Salvo
   N         S          Atingido
   S         N          Atingido
   S         S          A Salvo
```

No exemplo, essa tabela em C tem os 4 resultados

```
    int destino[2][2] = {0, 1, 1, 0};  // os resultados
```

#### Exemplo em C

Claro que já tendo os 4 casos do exemplo seria melhor poder testar logo com esses e ler de um arquivo, e apenas se desse certo leria da entrada padrão, como o caso do programa no tal Online Judge.
Ler dados do teclado é muito mais chato e complicado que ler de um simples arquivo que você digita no próprio IDE, e vou mostrar no exemplo que pode usar o mesmo código...

Eis os dados de entrada de exemplo

```
4 repeticoes
9 pulos
1 3 2 3 3 1 2 2 1
JJSSSJSSJ
49 pulos
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
SSSSSSSSSSSSSSJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ
4 pulos
1 2 2 1
SJJS
1 pulo
1
J
```

Dependendo de como você ler em C pode até deixar texto no arquivo pra não ter que ficar procurando os testes no meio do arquivo...

E o resultado esperado

```
4
49 
2
0
```

Então o mais simples é colocar esses dados em um arquivo, como

```
exemplo.txt
```

E o programa em C aceita um parâmetro opcional que é o óbvio nome do arquivo. Assim você pode testar com dados de um arquivo que digita no próprio editor, e se não usar o parâmetro o programa lê do teclado mesmo...

#### Rodando o exemplo

Os 4 testes óbvios: `2J 4J 2S 4S` lembrando que com a altura menor que 3 se pular se salva, e com a altura maior que 2 se pular é atingido, e 0 indica que não foi atingido...

```
SO>./f1-0903
1
1
2
J
0
SO>./f1-0903
1
1
4
J
1
SO> ./f1-0903
1
1
2
S
1
SO> ./f1-0903
1
1
4
S
0
```

Claro que a saída seria apenas a quarta linha de cada caso, o número de *hits*.

```
0
1
1
0
```

#### chamando com o arquivo que tem os dados do exemplo

```
SO> ./f1-0903 exemplo.txt
4
49
2
0
```

Claro que `f1-0903` era o nome do programa na máquina de teste.

E esse é o resultado esperado.

#### lendo do arquivo OU do teclado

```
    FILE* ent;
    if (argc > 1)
    {  // veio algo entao e o nome do arquivo
        ent = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if (ent == NULL) return -1;
    }
    else
        ent = stdin;  // nao veio o arquivo...
```

Basta isso. Se não vier nada na linha de comando lê os dados do teclado.

Não faz sentido ficar digitando dados a toa para cada teste.

No exemplo usei `fgets()` para ler os valores que vem sozinhos na linha pra não perder tempo com lances de buffer, e para poder escrever no resto da linha pra não ter que ficar contando no editor :)

Depois de ler o total de testes o programa tem um loop para fazer os testes, e termina.

O loop dos testes lê o total de disparos e o vetor de alturas.

Não é preciso ler o vetor de ações porque de nada serve. Só precisamos saber a ação porque já temos a altura do tiro, e então pode somar direto no número de *hits* em uma linha de acordo com a tabela que tem acima

```
            mortes += destino[altura[t] < 3][mov == 'J'];
```

#### o programa todo

```
/*
 EXEMPLO C relativo a questao
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/526544
 e ao problea 1250 do URI Online Judge
 https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1250
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char  linha[200];
    FILE* ent;
    if (argc > 1)
    {  // veio algo entao e o nome do arquivo
        ent = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if (ent == NULL) return -1;
    }
    else
        ent = stdin;  // nao veio o arquivo...

    int destino[2][2] = {0, 1, 1, 0};  // os resultados

    fgets(linha, sizeof linha, ent);
    int N   = 0;  // o total de testes
    int res = sscanf(linha, "%d", &N);
    if (res < 0) return -1;

    // os N testes
    for (int n = 0; n < N; n += 1)
    {  // o teste 'n'
        int T = 0;  // disparos
        fgets(linha, sizeof linha, ent);
        res = sscanf(linha, "%d", &T);
        if (res < 0) return -2;
        // os 'T' disparos
        int altura[50];
        for (int t = 0; t < T; t += 1)
        {
            // le o vetor das alturas
            res = fscanf(ent, "%d", altura + t);
            if (res < 0) return -2;
        };  // for(t)
        fgets(linha, sizeof linha, ent);  // le o '\n' da linha anterior

        // calcula as mortes afinal
        char mov;  // movimento
        int  mortes = 0;
        for (int t = 0; t < T; t += 1)
        {   // para cada altura testa se foi atingido
            res = fscanf(ent, "%c", &mov);
            if (res < 0) return -2;
            mortes += destino[altura[t] < 3][mov == 'J'];
        };  // for(t)
        printf("%d\n", mortes);
        fgets(linha, sizeof linha, ent);
    };  // for (n)
    fclose(ent);
    return 0;
}
```

#### sobre seu programa

```
    int rep, mov, ace, i, i2;
    scanf("%d", &rep);
    for (i = 0; i < rep; i++)
    {
        ace = 0;
        scanf("%d", &mov);
```

Evite esse tipo de construção. Mesmo sendo um programa para "competição" mostre ao sujeito que estiver usando o programa o que espera ler. E não seria demais mostrar o que leu. Muitas o programa dá errado porque está achando que leu algo e não leu, como ao confundir `'0'` a letra e `0` o número.

Teste sempre o retorno de `scanf()`. Como nesse caso só tem um especificador pode retornar `1`, `0` ou `-1`. Se ler o número vai retornar `1`, mas se não ler qual o sentido de seguir com o programa? Experimente teclar um `x` nessa hora...

No `for` declare sempre a variável de controle do loop. Esse era um problema da linguagem, corrigido há uns 40 anos.

Evite declarar mais de uma variável por linha. Linhas são grátis. E inicialize todas as variáveis. Vai te salvar muitas vezes.

Use nomes mais expressivos, em especial em casos como `i` e `i2` que são globais em `main()`

Não pode declarar

```
        int tiro[mov];
```

deve ser ser um valor conhecido em tempo de compilação, como

```
    int tiro[300];
```

Ou deve alocar na hora, como em

```
    int*    tiro = (int*) malloc(300 * sizeof (int))
```

#### exemplo

Recortando e colando de seu programa, compare com um modo comum de escrever isso:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int rep = 0;
    int mov = 0;
    int ace = 0;
    
    printf("rep? : ");
    int res = scanf("%d", &rep);
    if (res < 0 ) return - 1;
    printf("rep = %d\n", rep);

    for (int i = 0; i < rep; i++)
    {
        ace = 0;
        printf("mov? : ");
        res = scanf("%d", &mov);
        if (res < 0) return -2;
        if (mov > 512) mov = 512;  // um limite...
        printf("mov = %d\n", mov);

        // le os tiro[0] a tiro[mov-1]
        int* tiro = (int*)malloc(mov * sizeof(int));
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < mov; i2++)
        {
            res = scanf("%d", &tiro[i2]);
            if (res < 0) return -3;
        }
        // mostra os caras...
        printf("Tiro:\n");

        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < mov; i2++)
        {
            printf("%d ", tiro[i2]);
            if ((i2 % 4) == 3) printf("\n");  // 4 por linha
        }
        printf("\n");
        free(tiro); // apaga o vetor
    }
    return 0;
}
```

que aloca o vetor 'tiro[]` a cada repetição e apaga ao final

#### saída

```
rep? : 1
rep = 1
mov? : 8
mov = 8
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
Tiro:
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

Comment: +1, mas com ressalva. Só faz sentido, vc verificar retorno de erro, se o erro precisa ser tratado e se você sabe como fazer isso. No caso do `scanf` e programação competitiva, se por alguma razão o seu programa não ler a entrada a sua solução não vai passar o teste e o tratamento que você dá com `return -1;` não acrescenta nada já que o resultado será **WA 100%** que seria o mesmo caso a sua solução fosse incorreta. Aqui, você tem duas alternativas, ignorar completamente o retorno de `scanf()` - o que eu faria - ou tratar invocando `abort()` e o URI informa que houve um runtime error.

Comment: Sim e não, @VanderSantos. Isso porque antes de submeter o programa você precisa dele pronto e testando pelo erro e mostrando o que leu você provavelmente chega mais rápido ao momento de submeter o resultado, e isso é a competição afinal. Depois que estiver certo leva minutos para retirar esses testes. Para estar pronto sem esses testes pode levar muito mais tempo do que leva pra tirar isso.

Comment: Desculpe @arfneto, sou novo aqui no SO. Acabei cometendo um erro sobre o número da questão, corrigi isso agora no enunciado. No caso, o problema que tive é que em algumas ocasiões o valor na posição 0 do array tiro era substituído e não sabia porque isso está acontecendo

Comment: Entendo. Mesmo corrigindo as coisas de que falei persiste a corrupção? Vou ver depois se acho algo

Comment: Não, a corrupção foi corrigida. Pode só me explicar um pouco melhor como funciona o array tiro? Comecei a pouco tempo com C, então estou bem perdido em algumas coisas ainda

Comment: Eu vi o tal problema. O único array de que precisa é o das alturas dos tiros, porque as ações vem juntas. Vou deixar um exemplo que talvez ajude a entender